# td background stretches into tr even though height is applied

Tags: css, mobile, html-table

I have my td's set with a height on them, but on mobile devices such as my iPad and iPhone, the td background and border flows out of the td and into the tr. I recreated my exact code to show you what it NORMALLY looks like on my desktop, but as you can imagine there's probably a bug in my code which is allowing it to flow into the tr's

```
#tstyle2 {
    width: 1000px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e8e6e6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

#tstyle2 tr {
    height: 160px;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: none;
    width: 1000px;
}

#tstyle2 td {
    border-top: none;
    display: block;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: white;
    border-left: 4px solid #bd6ec1;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #b5b6b6;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/338cR/

Comment: is that apple specific for the mobile devices, or the same for android and winphone?

Comment: do you have any viewport declarations?

Comment: Seems to be all browsers but firefox

I tried both chrome and safari on mobile - It's off...

As well as chrome on computer - It's off

Comment: And it seems to be fine in JSfiddle -.-

Comment: keeg: What do you mean by viewpoint declarations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution:

I had to add

```
 display:block;
```

to the #tstyle2 tr {}

and then add

```
width: 1000px;
```

to the #tstyle2 td {}